# Omega, well ordering and the cumulative hierarchy $V$.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Hi I need help with a problem of set theory.
I'm not sure how to prove that the well ordering on $\omega$ isomorphic to $\omega+\omega$ belongs to the level $V_{\omega+\omega}$ in the hierarchy $V$.

any help?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Any relation on $\omega$ is a subset of $\mathcal P (\mathcal P ( \mathcal P(\omega)))$.

$V_{\omega + \omega} = \bigcup_{\beta < \omega + \omega} \mathcal P (V_\beta)$ and $\omega \in V_{\omega + 1}$.

Now combine these two to obtain the desired.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\omega$ is a very particular set, it belongs $V_{\omega+1}$. It is not hard to calculate and see that $\omega\times\omega$ belongs to $V_{\omega+5}$ (or even less), so every subset of it would be in $V_{\omega+6}$ and in particular the subsets which are well-orders of any order type.

Comment: Still having fun with Igor, I see.  It's simply astounding that some people don't realise that science advances _precisely because_ it is incorrect, and is willing to adjust itself.  Otherwise we'd still be adhering to Ptolemy's conception of a geo-centric universe, since that was science (and math)!

Comment: @Arthur: If I won't do that, I'll have to resort to actually working! :-)

Comment: Any pair $(n,m)$ is in $V_\omega$, so $\omega\times\omega$ and all its subsets are in $V_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: @Andres: Ah, yes. That is a good observation. I have a vague memory of this being pointed out before in the comments to my answer on this site...

Comment: This is a test$\vphantom{@Arthur}$. Did you get pinged? :-)